# What is the best way to go installing Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb

I have an old computer which already has Windows 8.1 on it. I would rather not completely remove Windows from my old computer. I may want to sell my old desktop in the future, and I don't have the product key or installation CD anymore. Instead, I want to try and "dual boot" Ubuntu with Windows 8.1. I checked various sites and they say using a "bootable USB" is the best choice, or the only choice. I want to know how I should go about this? I've heard from another source that I can just run an installer in Windows without needing to touch the BIOS or anything. Unfortunately, I can't get any more help from them. I have already written an ISO image of Ubuntu onto an 8 gb flashdrive using this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

I guess my actual question is how do I run this? And another question is with that tutorial, will it use my computers harddrive and just partition it to have Ubuntu on it, or will it use the very small and limited space on my flashdrive to store installed files & Ubuntu system files themselves?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're concerned about recovering from a mistake made during installation, **make a complete disk image** and verify it before installing an OS. There are a number of tools to do so, such as as [Macrrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree).
2. Since you've made the ISO boot image, you'll need to set your PC to boot from it. Entering setup is peculiar to each PC model, so check your manual.

   - Enter BIOS/UEFI setup and disable [Windows Fast Startup](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/fast-startup-turn-on-or-off-in-windows-8.6320/), if it is set.
   - Older versions of Linux required disabling Secure Boot, but Ubuntu 18.04 and later work well with Secure Boot set.
   - Change Boot Order so that "USB hard drive" or similar description is first.
3. With Ubuntu, you can first test the OS *without having to install it* -- nothing need be written to the hard disk drive. Boot from USB and choose the option to try Ubuntu without installing.
4. If you like the new OS, you can then choose to permanently install it, either stand-alone (deleting the old Windows OS *and all data*), or dual-boot with Windows 8. My experience is that either work well, but if the HDD has little room, Ubuntu-only makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Windows 8 installation key, then the computer does not have a lot of value (no or very little value).  To me, this is the governing point. I cannot see much demand for a Windows 8 computer.

So let Windows 8 go and convert the machine to Ubuntu.

The computer would have at least as much value with a working Ubuntu System as an old Windows 8 system with no key.

If you try dual-booting and something goes wrong you (apparently) cannot get back (no ability to reinstall Windows 8).

Comment: It has one I believe, I just don't have it. Like, the system is activated and everything. However, I can't say the key if I was asked for it.

Comment: There is not much demand anyway for a Windows 8 computer today.

Comment: I get that, but do you possibly have an answer to my question ;-;

Comment: Ubuntu is a useful system (I have an Ubuntu machine here) so converting to Ubuntu is the suggestion I offered. If you try dualbooting, and have an error, you may not be able to go back.